# Microsoft Graph ChatMessage Namespace Missing in C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I'm following the [Microsoft Graph tutorial to create and send a chat message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=csharp) to a Microsoft Teams channel from C#.

However, I'm getting an error when following the first example when trying to create a `ChatMessage` object. (`var chatMessage = new ChatMessage...`) The error is:

> The type or namespace name 'ChatMessage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

I've added the following references to my project already but none of them seem to contain the `ChatMessage` class definition:

- `Microsoft.Graph`
- `Microsoft.Graph.Core`
- `Microsoft.Graph.Auth`

The [ChatMessage documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessage?view=graph-rest-beta) gives me a little more information on the `ChatMessage` resource type but doesn't tell me where I should get it from.

The only other thing I've found is [`Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat.ChatMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.chat.chatmessage), but I can't find `windows.applicationmodel.chat` in Nuget, and I'm not sure if this is actually correct as there's no mention of it on the Graph tutorial page.

What am I doing wrong to be able to use the `ChatMessage` object in the tutorial?

Comment: Windows.ApplicationModel.Chat is only available in UWP as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Have you added a reference to Microsoft.Graph.Beta?

Comment: I have run in to the same problem as you, so now I know I need to use the beta version of the package - but just wanted to ask you did you get this to work as in send a message to a channel?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to call into the Beta version of Microsoft Graph  (i.e. `/beta/...`), you need to use the [Microsoft.Graph.Beta](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph.Beta) NuGet package, *not* the [Microsoft.Graph](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Graph) package. The later only contains APIs that have been released (i.e. `/v1.0/...`).